# LINQ query to Data Table returns incorrect results

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want to LINQ query to Datatable in order to select the Names with specific ID, but it returns the length of Names not the strings, here is some sample code:

```
    private void btnShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable CL = new DataTable();
        DataRow rt;
        CL.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
        CL.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));           

        for (int i = 0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            rt = CL.NewRow();
            rt[0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            rt[1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            CL.Rows.Add(rt);
        }

        var results = from myRow in CL.AsEnumerable()
                  where myRow.Field<string>("ID") == "1"
                  select myRow.Field<string>("Name").ToString();

       dataGridView2.DataSource = results.ToList();

     }
```

thanx in advance

Comment: What content is in your datatable beforehand?

Comment: just two columns ID and Names

Comment: You don't need `ToString()` at end since return data will be string itself.

Comment: @user2102572 I said content, not structure :)

Comment: Couldn't the see content in the question. Where `CL` is getting populated? Post that as well, might be error in populating the dataTable.

Comment: Even without ToString() it also retrieves the length

Comment: Assuming your `DataGridView` is defined correctly and your `DataTable` contains relevant data, I cannot reproduce your issue. How are the columns defined in your `DataGridView`?

Comment: the datatable just filled with DataGridView data

Comment: A good way to see if it's a problem with your query and projection or with the grid would be to set a breakpoint where you set the DataSource and inspect the content of `results`.

Comment: You aren't posting the full amount of code, how is `DataTable` populated? Could you look at the DataTable in debug before you hit the query and update the question with your **content**. What you have posted will get a `IEnumerable<string>` where each one is the value of that column. One would suspect the length values are in the `Name` column.

Comment: What are the columns of your datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that `Value` is returning the value you aren't suspecting.

First off, try:

```
for (int i = 0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  rt = CL.NewRow();
  string value1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
  string value2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
  //Breakpoint here, check the values of value1 and value2
  CL.Rows.Add(rt);
}
```

I would also try a different variation of your query.

```
string[] names = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row["Id"] == 1).Select(row => row["Name"].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Then check names at this point. Please comment back the results of the first section of the answer to see what the values are.

Comment: Mr. Luke first of all when I set breakpoint at that specific line it refers id=1 even without ToString();

Comment: by the way I applied your query, it just bind column named "Length" without any rows

Comment: What are the values of `value1` and `value2` respectively?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable CL = new DataTable();
    DataRow rt;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow row;
    CL.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
    CL.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));           

    for (int i = 0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        rt = CL.NewRow();
        rt[0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        rt[1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        CL.Rows.Add(rt);
    }

    IEnumerable<DataRow> results = from myRow in CL.AsEnumerable()
                                   where myRow.Field<string>("ID") == "1"
                                   select myRow;

            foreach (var re in results)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(st.Field<string>("Name"));
            }
   dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;

 }
```